# Sharepoint 2010 timer job, value does not fall within expected range

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, timer-jobs

I am facing strange in sharepoint timer jobs on production server.
Here is query which is used to query a list through timer job.

```
 var incompleteJobs = from queue in JobQueue                                           
                                         select queue;
```

above code fetches items from list which are used for processing.
this code works fine in development,testing environments.but in some production environments.
It works well for some time(1 day,2 days) and then time job crashed with this error
"value does not fall within the expected range"

Any logical reason why this would happen?

Comment: Are you sure you get this error on this particular line?

Comment: yes,based on logs.and increasing resource throttling works.but I wonder why It works for some time initially and then stops..